# Task Scheduling Laravel5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a question about setting up cron task on a remote server. I'm using CPanel and I tried using Bitvise to run my cron task but the site doesn't allow SSH.

Basically I tried copy and paste this `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` and set the timing to everyminute.

I tried to send myself an email every minute.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $eController = new emailController;
        $eController->tryEmail();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Nothing seems to work. I simply don't know why. I think it's because the server I hosted my website probably doesn't allow artisan code. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Where did you copy and paste this command `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: at CPanel Cronjobs tab. I set the task to every minute meaning it has * * * * * prefix.

Comment: are you sure the `/path/to/artisan` is complete, this needs to be the complete Unix path? In other words, it's not the relative path.

Comment: I figured I took the code from documentation page literally. I think I need to figure out the path to the artisan folder, but where is it located in the laravel5.1 project.

Comment: The `artisan.php` is located in the root Laravel folder.

Comment: still having some difficulty to trigger my function. so I modified my cron command to php /app/artisan  schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1. I'm using a remote server at a web host.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the above comment, you need the fill path to your artisan command. This totally depends on your Shared hosting configuration, we cannot help you on that. Please refer to your hosting support, if you cannot find the complete path.

Comment: The path will be something like that: /var/<some_shared_hosting_id>/some/paths/app/artisan